# Populate XML table after filling it in JavaScript Controller

Tags: javascript, sapui5, innerhtml, xmltable

I have an empty XML table in my SAPUi5 application:

```
<m:Table id="testdata3"></m:Table>
```

In my JavaScript controller, I use the SheetJS library to upload an Excel file and then read the data into the table, using "sheet_to_html".
When debugging my code I have all the data together and also my console.log call shows me data in the innerHTML of my table. But for some reason, the table stays empty. So basically nothing happens in the front-end. I feel like I'm missing a "return" or "populate" or something in that direction to load the table with the new data.
Any ideas?

```
 _import : function(file) {
            var oTable = this.getView().byId('testdata3');
            if(file && window.FileReader){
                var reader = new FileReader();
                var result = {}, data;
            reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    var rawLog = reader.result;
                    data = e.target.result;
                    var wb = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'binary'});
                    var first_sheet_name = wb.SheetNames[0];
                    var worksheet = wb.Sheets[first_sheet_name]; 
                    oTable.innerHTML = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_html(worksheet);
                    console.log(oTable.innerHTML);
}
```

**Update: code for model**

```
_import : function(file) {

            var oTable = this.getView().byId('testdata3');
            if(file && window.FileReader){
                var reader = new FileReader();
                var result = {}, data;
                var that = this;
                reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    var rawLog = reader.result;
                    data = e.target.result;
                    var wb = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'binary'});
                    var first_sheet_name = wb.SheetNames[0];
                    var worksheet = wb.Sheets[first_sheet_name]; 
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
                        sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel,'myResultModel');
                        that.getView().byId("testdata3").setModel(oModel);

                        var oColumns = [];
*// I'm iterating over the column names and pushing them to my table works fine, but I'm then stuck with proceeding and pushing the rest of the data to my table..*

                       var cells = Object.keys(worksheet);
                                for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(cells).length; i++) {
                                    if( cells[i].indexOf('1') > -1)
                                    {
                                        oColumns.push(worksheet[cells[i]].v);
                                    }
                                }
                            var oColumnNames = [];
                            $.each(oColumns, function(i, value) {
                            oColumnNames.push({
                                    Text: oColumns[i]
                                });
                            });
    oModel.setProperty("/columnNames", oColumnNames);
        oModel.setProperty("/columnNames", oColumnNames);
                            var oTemplate = new Column({
                                header: new Label({
                                    text: "{Text}"
                                })
                            });
        oTable.bindAggregation("columns", "/columns", oTemplate);
                    };
                };
            },
```

**EDIT here is an other attempt I tried, when debugging everything looks fine but the table stays empty anyways..**

```
        onXLSXupload : function(e) {
        this._import(e.getParameter("files") && e.getParameter("files")[0]);
    },
    _import : function(file) {
        console.log(file);
        var oTable = this.getView().byId('testdata3');
        if(file && window.FileReader){
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var result = {}, data;
            var that = this;
            reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                var rawLog = reader.result;
                data = e.target.result;
                var wb = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'binary'});
                var first_sheet_name = wb.SheetNames[0];
                var worksheet = wb.Sheets[first_sheet_name]; 
                  wb.SheetNames.forEach(function(first_sheet_name) {

                       var roa = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(wb.Sheets[first_sheet_name]);

                       if(roa.length > 0){

                         result[first_sheet_name] = roa;

                       }

                     });
                     var data = result[Object.keys(result)[0]];

                     for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){

                         var excelRows = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({cells:[

                           new sap.m.Text({text: data[i][Object.keys(data[i])[0]]}),

                           new sap.m.Text({text: data[i][Object.keys(data[i])[1]]})

                         ]});

                         that.getView().byId("testdata3").addItem(excelRows );

                       }
            };
        };
    },
```

I'm simply struggling to find the right approach of binding the items to my table.. I'm wondering if it has something to do with my XML view or the controller file..

**Update with answer from @MatthijsMennen** **Now still struggling because the items are only populated in one column**

```
        _import : function(file) {
        var oTable = this.getView().byId('testdata3');
        if(file && window.FileReader){
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var result = {}, data;
            var that = this;
            reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                var rawLog = reader.result;
                data = e.target.result;
                var wb = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'binary'});
                var first_sheet_name = wb.SheetNames[0];
                var worksheet = wb.Sheets[first_sheet_name]; 
                var aColumns = that.getColumnNames(worksheet);
                var aData = that.getRowData(worksheet, result);alert(aData);
                var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
                oModel.setData({
                    columns: aColumns,
                    rows: aData
                });
                oTable.setModel(oModel);
                oTable.bindAggregation("columns", "/columns", function(index, context) {
                    return new sap.m.Column({
                        header: new sap.m.Label({
                            text: context.getObject().columnId
                        })
                    });
                });

                oTable.bindAggregation("items", "/rows", function(index, context){
                    return new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
                        cells: [
                            new sap.m.Text({text: context.getObject().cellId })
                        ]
                    });
                });

            };
        };
    },
    getColumnNames: function(worksheet) {
        var oColumns = [];
        var cells = Object.keys(worksheet);
        for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(cells).length; i++) {
            if (cells[i].indexOf("1") > -1) {
                var columnName = worksheet[cells[i]].v;
                oColumns.push({
                    columnId: columnName
                });


            }
        }

        return oColumns;
    },

    getRowData: function(worksheet, result) {

            var roa = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet);

            if(roa.length > 0){

                result[worksheet] = roa;

            }
        var data = result[Object.keys(result)[0]];
        console.log(data.length);
        var i; var x;
        var oCells = []
        for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            for(var x = 0; x < data.length; x ++) {
                var excelRows = data[i][Object.keys(data[i])[x]];
                    console.log(data[i][Object.keys(data[i])[x]])
                oCells.push({ cellId: excelRows});
            }
        }
        return oCells;
    },
```

**update with for loop for columnlistitems**

```
oTable.bindAggregation("items", "/rows", function(index, context) {
                    var roa = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet);

                    if(roa.length > 0){

                        result[worksheet] = roa;

                    }
                    for(var i = 0; i < roa.length; i++){

                        return new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
                            cells: [
                                new Text({ text :context.getObject().cellId })
                                ]
                        })
                    };
                });
```

Comment: What happens if you delete the table at runtime from your view and re-add it afterwards?

Comment: @Matthijs Mennens Hmm I don't feel like that's the best solution for performance etc.?

Comment: No, but it helps to establish why this is happening. Maybe your table just doesn't get refreshed. Just trying to clarify things here.

Comment: Oh sorry about that! @MatthijsMennens
I tried removing it with "oTable.remove();" but that's not working..
I can imagine that it's not refreshing!

Comment: shouldnt the inner html be generated by the framework? I guess it could lead to problems if you just assign a new value, i mean how is the control supposed to know you are doing that? Are you shure you follow best practice here? I guess would be more appropriate to load your data into a model and bind that to the table or smth similar

Comment: @Erch true! That's what I tried before but I just coulnd't figure out how to bind the model to my table. So I tried a new attempt with that innerHTML. 
Would you be willing to help me out here and help me binding the data?

Comment: Maybe if you could show us what your model looks like, we could help you bind it to a table.

Comment: Sure! I'll add it to the code @MatthijsMennens

Comment: @MatthijsMennens did that help? I also added another attempt to read everything in the table. But it simply stays empty..

Comment: I'm looking at it now, but I need to add XLSX so I can test it. Looking in to it.

Comment: Btw, you should split up your functions some more. Several short functions are more readable than one long function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a small example here with SheetJS. The column names get extracted from the worksheet, but you still need to get the rows from the worksheet. I added some dummy data for the rows.

Hope this helps.

**View**

```
    <Table id="testdata3" />
    <u:FileUploader change="onChange" buttonText="Upload" />
```

**Controller**

```
    onChange: function(oEvent) {
        var file = oEvent.getParameter("files")[0];
        var oTable = this.byId("testdata3");
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var that = this;
        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            var data = e.target.result;
            var wb = XLSX.read(data, {
                type: "binary"
            });

            var firstSheetName = wb.SheetNames[0];
            var worksheet = wb.Sheets[firstSheetName];
            var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
            var aColumns = that.getColumnNames(worksheet);
            var aData = that.getRowData(worksheet);
            var aCells = that.getCells(aColumns);

            oModel.setData({
                columns: aColumns,
                rows: aData
            });

            oTable.setModel(oModel);
            oTable.bindAggregation("columns", "/columns", function(index, context) {
                return new sap.m.Column({
                    header: new sap.m.Label({
                        text: context.getObject().columnId
                    })
                });
            });

            oTable.bindAggregation("items", "/rows", new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
                // CHANGE ACCORDINGLY OR MAKE DYNAMIC
                cells: aCells
            }));
        };

    },

    getColumnNames: function(worksheet) {
        var oColumns = [];
        var cells = Object.keys(worksheet);
        for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(cells).length; i++) {
            if (cells[i].indexOf("1") > -1) {
                var columnName = worksheet[cells[i]].v;
                oColumns.push({
                    columnId: columnName
                });
            }
        }
        return oColumns;
    },

    getRowData: function() {
        var aItems = [];
        // DO YOUR THING HERE
        aItems[0] = {
            value0: "testvalue0",
            value1: "testvalue1",
            value2: "testvalue2",
            value3: "testvalue3",
            value4: "testvalue4"
        };

        return aItems;
    },

    getCells: function(aColumns) {
        var cells = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < aColumns.length; i++) {
            cells[i] = new sap.m.Text({
                text: "{value" + i + "}"
            });

        }

        return cells;
    }
```

**Excel example**

[image: Example]

Comment: awesome works perfect for the ColumnNames!
I had that before, too but in the documentation of SheetJS I can't find anything about how to get the rest of the table data.. I tried different things, since I can retrieve the data from the JSON model but I don'T know how to loop through it correctly. Do you have any ideas? I'm a newbie to all of this, sorry!

Comment: It will be the same thing as the column names, but indexOf can't contain 1. Loop through all row numbers and add them like that. I'll take a look at it ASAP if you can't find it.

Comment: Here is what I figured out:
var data = result[Object.keys(result)[0]];
var i; var x;
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
 var columns = data[i];
 for(var x = 0; x < data.length; x ++) {
  var excelRows = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({cells:[
             new sap.m.Text({text: data[i][Object.keys(data[i])[x]]}),
              console.log(data[i][Object.keys(data[i])[x]])
         ]});
        
       that.getView().byId("testdata3").addItem(excelRows );
       }
}

the only thing I'm missing now: switch column --> now it's all displayed in only one column..

Comment: I added my new code to my question so it's better to see the structure..

Comment: You added only one cell. You should create a cell for each entry in the row

Comment: Hm I understand, but how do I loop that? I tried this (look at update) but that's still not working-..

Comment: I added a small example on how to dynamically create cells. Hope this helps you past your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In one of my projects I needed to create table dynamically from controller.

Here is how I did hoping it helps you:

**VIEW**

```
            <Table id="tableTask"
            inset="false">
            <headerToolbar>
                <OverflowToolbar id="otbSubheader">
                    <ToolbarSpacer/>
                    <SearchField id="taskSearchBox" search="onSearchOrClearPressed" liveChange="onSearchTasks" showSearchButton="false">
                        <layoutData><OverflowToolbarLayoutData minWidth="200px" maxWidth="300px" shrinkable="true"/></layoutData>
                    </SearchField>
                </OverflowToolbar>
            </headerToolbar>
            <columns>
                <!-- Columns created in controller -->
            </columns>
            <items>
                <ColumnListItem id="columnsListItemTask" press="onPressListItem" type="Navigation">
                    <cells>
                        <!-- Cells created in controller -->
                    </cells>
                </ColumnListItem>
            </items>
        </Table>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
onInit: function(){

    ...

    // Get columns aggregation of table
    let oColumns = this.getView().byId('columnsListItemTask');

    // Define table cells
    let cellToAdd1 = new sap.m.Text('textCell1',{            
        text: "{path/to/modelValue1}"
    });

    let cellToAdd2 = new sap.m.Text('textCell2',{            
        text: "{path/to/modelValue2}"
    });

    let cellToAdd3 = new sap.m.Text('textCell3',{            
        text: "{path/to/modelValue3}"
    });

    let cellToAdd4 = new sap.m.Text('textCell4',{            
        text: "{path/to/modelValue4}"
    });

    // Add cells (in this case 4 columns)
    oColumns.addCell(cellToAdd1); 
    oColumns.addCell(cellToAdd2); 
    oColumns.addCell(cellToAdd3); 
    oColumns.addCell(cellToAdd4);

    var jsonModel = new JSONModel(yourModel);
    this.getView().setModel(jsonModel);

    // Get Table by id
    let oTable = this.getView().byId('tableTask');
    oTable.removeAllItems();        //Remove old items if present                                       
    oTable.removeAllAggregation();  //Remove aggregations 
    oTable.bindAggregation('items', {
        path:'/rowsData',   // field name of you JSONModel containing data rows
        template: oColumns,  // rowTemplate of cells
    });

    ...

}
```

**UPDATE**

You can do a for loop to add dynamically any number of columns:

onInit: function(){

```
...

// Get columns aggregation of table
let oColumns = this.getView().byId('columnsListItemTask');

let cellToAdd;

// This for loop in each columns I need to generate
// (in my case they are defined in a database and I get it with AJAX request)
for(let key in allCellsToGenearte){
    cellToAdd = new sap.m.Text({            
        text: allCellsToGenearte["modelPath"]
    });
    oColumns.addCell(cellToAdd); 
}

// Get Table by id
let oTable = this.getView().byId('tableTask');
oTable.removeAllItems();        //Remove old items if present                                       
oTable.removeAllAggregation();  //Remove aggregations 
oTable.bindAggregation('items', {
    path:'/rowsData',   // field name of JSON Model containing data rows
    template: oColumns,  // rowTemplate of cells
});

...

}
```

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't help me since I'm trying to fill my table without predefining the column or row number. It should be possible to upload any excel file, no matter what size it has or what structure.

Comment: even in my projects number of columns was not the same everytime. In my code example i reported only the important parts. I update my answer with a for loop.